# delete string first character with index strange behavior

Tags: php

If I do:

```
$str = "+12";
$str[0] = "-"; // -12
```

But when I want to remove character like:

```
$str[0] = '';
```

Dumping it outputs black clubs question mark:

```
�12
```

How this works?

Comment: Seems to be [working fine](http://codepad.org/enMGR9L8). Make sure you're assigning empty character.

Comment: @Rikesh no you have to dump it, not echo

Comment: Works fine for me! Please make sure you show us here your **full** and **real** code!

Comment: It isn't strange behaviour: you're trying to replace a character in a string with something that isn't a character (an empty string is not a character): you can only replace a character with another (single) character using this syntax, else the result is unpredictable

Comment: See the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) for more details, and read the warnings - `Assigning empty string assigns NULL byte` - this is documented behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @MarkBaker the PHP docs states Assigning empty string assigns null byte. You could use the substr for this. Use the code below

```
<?php
$str = "+12";
$str[0] = "-"; // -12
$str = substr($str,1);
echo $str;
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$str = "+12";
echo $str = substr($str, 1);
```

Comment: I know how to do this in such ways, also with trim, but I'm not asking how to do. but how it works

Comment: $str = "+12";$str[0] = "-";$str[0] = ''; echo $str; When I did this, it echoed 12 correctly. NO � - symbol at beginning. On which browser you are checking?